# How do I get the surrounding data related to my userId using flutter and firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, dart

While using flutter I am able to successfully get the `UserId`, however I want to be able get more user data (using the UserId)

Surrounding Information:

[image: as seen here]

With the userId how would I go about printing the users; name bio, membership... etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using Realtime Database, then to get the other data, you can do the following:

```
db = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("Users");
db.once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot){
  Map<dynamic, dynamic> values = snapshot.value;
     values.forEach((key,values) {
      print(values);
      print(values["name"]);
    });
 });
```

First add a reference to node `Users` then use the `forEach` method to iterate inside the retrieved `Map` and retrieve the other values.

Answer (score 0):

```
getUsers() async {
//here fbPath is reference to your users path

fbPath.once().then((user){
      if(user.value !=null){
      Map.from(user.value).forEach((k,v){
      //here users is List<Map>
      setState((){
          users.add(v);
      });
     }
   }
});
}

//Or

getUsers() async {
   //here fbPath is reference to your users path
   //and userListener is StreamSubscription

   userListener = fbPath.onChildAdded.listen((user){
   //here users is List<Map>
   setState((){
       users.add(Map.from(user.snapshot.value));
    });
  });
}

//and cancel in dispose method by calling 

userListener.cancel();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

```
Future<dynamic> getWeightinKeg() async {
    final DocumentReference document =  Firestore.instance.collection('you_collection_name').document(user_id);
    await document.get().then<dynamic>(( DocumentSnapshot snapshot) async {
    final dynamic data = snapshot.data;
     print(data['name'].toString())
     //Do whatever you want to do with data here.  
    });
}
```